# select2: load remote data from several sources simultaneously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

I need some kind of omnisearch: when user types some name or serial number select2 sends several simultaneous ajax calls to retrieve employees, candidates and devices.
As soon as any of these calls returns data (for example employees) it is shown to user.

So if employee data is returned first we show it. As soon as candidates data is returned we combine it with employees data, sort data by name and show it to user again.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to code by yourself such a thing, by default select2 only loads data attached to the select box, it's your responsability to write javascript that will behave in the following way and it's a non-trivial code.

In general your idea will be load (with multiple async calls) the locations you want and store the data you fetched, after performing operations you need (merging with another json) in the select box and refresh it.

Answer (score 0):

I would think you would want to write this on the backend.  Have an endpoint that collalesses all the data you want.  Select 2 makes one ajax call to the endpoint to retrieve all the data you need in one go.